# Yii2 humanly understandable URLs

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, yii, yii2

Good morning!)

The urls does not work correctly. I have a clean yii2 template. I uncommented in config/web.php this block:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

Added 'baseUrl'=> '' in requests in components,

Add in the root folder .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

In the web folder added:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Styles removed. When I delete 'baseUrl'=> '', they are returned. Link /site/about leads on the main page and not to the web/site/about.
In the Source code the css plugged.

```
<link href="/assets/7fb759e5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

Thank you! Good day)))

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess - your prettyurls are not working.

- make sure your apache / web server is working correctly with mod_rewrite
- remove .htaccess from root folder and set apache DocumentRoot to /whatever/path/is/there/tofolder/web (C:/xammp/htdocs/something/web)

btw. you should not set yii\helpers\BaseUrl property directly.